malformed_request_body when trying to create a firewall rule in Cloudflare using the API
When trying to create a new firewall rule in Cloudflare using their API, I receive the following error:
{
  "result": null,
  "success": false,
  "errors": [
    {
      "code": 10014,
      "message": "firewallrules.api.malformed_request_body"
    }
  ],
  "messages": []
}


This is the curl cmd:
curl --request POST \
  --url https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones/zone-id/firewall/rules \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer api-token' \
  --data '{ "filter": { "expression": "ip.src eq 212.00.34.132" }, "action": "allow", "description": "Test Whitelist IP" }'
{


I will appreciate help.

You need to do this in two steps, first one create a filter and second one create a rule, something like:
curl --request POST \
"https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones/zone-id/filters" \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header "X-Auth-Email: <redacted>" \
--header "X-Auth-Key: <redacted>" \
--data '[{"expression": "ip.src eq 212.100.34.132", "description": "Test Whitelist IP"}]'

In Response you will have the filter Id:
{
  "result": [
    {
      "id": "8750209c994f4bd0897b51a78ec177e3",
      "expression": "ip.src eq 212.100.34.132",
      "paused": false,
      "description": "Test Whitelist IP"
    }
  ],
  "success": true,
  "errors": [],
  "messages": []
}

and for rule:
curl --request POST \
--url https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones/zone-id/firewall/rules \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header "X-Auth-Email: <redacted>" \
--header "X-Auth-Key: <redacted>" \
--data '[{ "filter": {"id": "8750209c994f4bd0897b51a78ec177e3"}, "action": "allow"}]'

Also, please check your IP address, it looks like it is incorrect, at least Cloudflare doesn't allow the creation of a rule with this IP address.
And keep in mind that Cloudflare Firewall Rules are deprecated, and better to use Cloudflare Custom rules.
